# Getting wrong option menu on particular position in listview

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, optionmenu

I have listview :
As shown in image below,when user press downarrow option menu is pop-up
there will be multiple post(i.e like Facebook), option-menu pop-up with different option
If user is owner of that post then menu option will be Edit post,delete post
if user is not owner than menu option will be Spam post
I have 2 menu for this.
It is not working according to requirement, if user is not owner of that post than also pop-up menu with Edit/delete get open

[image: option menu true]

[image: wrong option menu]

poupup_menu :

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity" >

    <item
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:id="@+id/one"
       android:title="Edit" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Delete"/>


</menu>
```

popup_menu_user :

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="Spam"/>

</menu>
```

What i am doing in Listview adapter for taking particual position :

Listview adapter :

```
ivOptionMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View tempView = (View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                pos = (Integer) v.getTag(R.integer.btnpluspos);
                tvPostDetail = (TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostDetail);
                positionItemFeed = String.valueOf(pos);
                if (post_user_id.equals(preferenceHelper.getID())) {

                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, v);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            String menuOption;
                            menuOption = (String) item.getTitle();
                            if (menuOption.equals("Edit")) {
                                editPost();
                            } else {
                                delete();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    popup.show();//showing popupuser menu
                } else {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx, v);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_user, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            //   Toast.makeText(ctx, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String menuOption;
                            menuOption = (String) item.getTitle();

                            if (menuOption.equals("Spam")) {
                                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
                                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        ctx);
                                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                                        // edit text
                                                        reasonSpam = userInput.getText().toString();
                                                        reportSpam(reasonSpam);
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                // create alert dialog
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                // show it
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.show();//showing popupuser menu
                }
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing i am comparing in :

`if (post_user_id.equals(preferenceHelper.getID()))` ,here i.e post_user_id is not getting , so menu is not poping up correct

```
 popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.one:
                                editPost();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.two:
                                delete();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.three:
                               /* reasonSpam = userInput.getText().toString();
                                reportSpam(reasonSpam);*/
                                return true;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                /** Showing the popupuser menu */
                popup.show();
```